# CipherInputStream hangs while reading data

Tags: java, io, aes, aes-gcm

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt some files, which I will be reading/writing using `FileIn/OutputStream`s piped through `CipherIn/OutputStream`s. Fairly simple in concept, and I've gotten this to work using raw byte arrays and `Cipher.doFinal`. So I know my encryption parameters (bit size, iv size, etc.) are correct. (Or at least functional?)

I'm able to write data through a `CipherOutputStream` just fine. However, when I try to read that data back through a `CipherInputStream`, it hangs indefinitely.

The only [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272959/cipherinputstream-hangs) I've found remains unanswered, and is potentially fundamentally different from my problem, as my problem will always have all the data available on disk, as opposed to the related problem's reliance on `Sockets`.

I've tried a number of solutions, the most obvious one being changing the buffer size (`data = new byte[4096];`). I've tried a number of values, including the size of the plaintext and the size of the encrypted data. None of these values work. The only solution I've found is avoiding using a `CipherInputStream` altogether, and instead relying on `Cipher.doFinal` and `Cipher.update`.

Am I missing something? It would be very nice to be able to use a `CipherInputStream`, rather than having to reinvent the wheel by using `Cipher.update`.

SSCCE:

```
private static final String AES_ALG = "aes_256/gcm/nopadding";
private static final int GCM_TAG_SIZE = 128;

private static void doEncryptionTest() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File f = new File("encrypted_random_data.dat");
    // 12-byte long iv
    byte[] iv = new byte[] {0x27, 0x51, 0x34, 0x14, -0x65, 0x4d, -0x67, 0x35, -0x63, 0x11, -0x02, -0x05};
    // 256-bit long key
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[] {0x55, -0x7f, -0x17, -0x29, -0x68, 0x25, 0x29, 0x5f, -0x27, -0x2d, -0x4d, 0x1b,
            0x25, 0x74, 0x57, 0x35, -0x23, -0x1b, 0x12, 0x7c, 0x1, -0xf, -0x60, -0x42, 0x1c, 0x61, 0x3e, -0x5,
            -0x13, 0x31, -0x48, -0x6e};
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    OutputStream os = encryptStream(key, iv, f);

    System.out.println("generating random data...");
    // 24MB of random data
    byte[] data = new byte[25165824];
    new Random().nextBytes(data);

    System.out.println("encrypting and writing data...");
    os.write(data);

    os.close();

    InputStream is = decryptStream(key, iv, f);

    System.out.println("reading and decrypting data...");
    // read the data in 4096 byte packets
    int n;
    data = new byte[4096];
    while ((n = is.read(data)) > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("read " + n + " bytes.");
    }

    is.close();
}

private static OutputStream encryptStream(SecretKey key, byte[] iv, File f) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, FileNotFoundException
{
    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_SIZE, iv);
    Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALG);
    enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);

    OutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f), enc);
    return os;
}

private static InputStream decryptStream(SecretKey key, byte[] iv, File f) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, FileNotFoundException
{
    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_SIZE, iv);
    Cipher dec = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALG);
    dec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);

    InputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(f), dec);
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't hang, it's just *very* slow. The `CipherInputStream` has a fixed input buffer of size 512, meaning it invokes the `Cipher#update(byte[], int, int)` method with at most 512 bytes at a time. Decrypting manually with bigger buffer sizes makes it a lot faster.

The reason is that calling `update` 50 000 times with 512 bytes takes a lot longer than calling it, say, 400 times with 65 kilobytes. I'm not sure why exactly, but there seems to be a constant overhead that you have to pay for every call to `update`, regardless of the amount of data you pass it.

Additionally be aware that you cannot use AES GCM to decrypt large files. By design, Sun's implementation of the cipher buffers the whole ciphertext in memory before decrypting it. You'd have to split the plaintext into small enough chunks and encrypt each chunk individually.

See also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20333/encryption-of-big-files-in-java-with-aes-gcm and  [How come putting the GCM authentication tag at the end of a cipher stream require internal buffering during decryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920906/how-come-putting-the-gcm-authentication-tag-at-the-end-of-a-cipher-stream-require-internal-buffering-).

Comment: Oh! You're right. It's strange to me that it hangs only on the first call of `CipherInputStream.read`, blocking the "read _n_ bytes" line. It's as if it's ignoring the buffer that I pass, opting to read the entire stream on the first call to `read`. Anyway, I've certainly waited long enough in my larger project, so I must have an error in it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I dug a bit deeper and it looks like the AES GCM cipher returns the plaintext only after doing `doFinal`. All intermediate updates return 0 bytes of plaintext: https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/026a6f1faddd522297fc61f6b06d73360be61344/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/GaloisCounterMode.java#L515

Comment: Because Sun chose to put the authentication tag at the end of the stream, `update` basically just buffers data and `doFinal` does all the work.

Comment: Relevant: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20333/encryption-of-big-files-in-java-with-aes-gcm and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920906/how-come-putting-the-gcm-authentication-tag-at-the-end-of-a-cipher-stream-require-internal-buffering-

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. After looking into it for a bit myself, I've realized that Java's GCM library is pretty awful. So, I've decided to use [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html), which actually allows me to use ChaCha20 in Java 1.8, which is exciting!